# Understanding Python documentation: how to know what a function returns?

Tags: python, conventions

I am having trouble understanding the background assumptions for reading Python documentation.

An example: Documentation for the `importlib.import_module` function can be found at https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module. The function documentation does not specify a return value for the function, but it (maybe obviously) returns the module it has just loaded.

I feel like there are actually a lot of functions for which the return value is not specified. I'm trying to decide which of the following options is closest to the truth.

1. The documentation of this function happens to be incomplete. Don't be so paranoid.
2. Whenever there is no specified return value, the function is assumed to be sufficiently auto-documenting that you can work it out. Just assign a name to the return value: `foo = f(bar)` and then `print(foo)`.
3. There is a conventional way of knowing what the return value is, and I need to learn the convention.

Case 3 is obviously the one that really worries me!

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1).  Any good documentation should state the return value on the initial lines, either with the return value to the left of the function, or with `Returns:` outdented,  then discuss what the arguments are.  Unfortunately, the people who are good programmers tend to be complete idiots in regards to explaining their inventions.  However, you should be thankful: the python docs are 10 times better than the ruby docs.

Comment: @7stud So you're saying Ruby programmers are more good than Python programmers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for `import_lib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) says what it returns.

> The most important difference is that import_module() returns the
>   specified package or module (e.g. pkg.mod), while _ _import__() returns
>   the top-level package or module (e.g. pkg).

Generally speaking: The documentation might be incomplete in places, if it is, do not assume it's a convention you know nothing about.

Comment: Obviously I failed here. As mentioned by 7stud, I was expecting to see the return value in a more highlighted position, but should have read more carefully through the whole thing. Anyway, thanks for your patience.

Comment: No worries. I too would prefer a formalized description for arguments and the return value in the Python documentation. At least in this case, reading the text gives you some knowledge about a different way how you can solve your problem.